# Create svg path from input value

Tags: reactjs, svg, input

Is there any chance to create svg element with path equal to converted input value?

Roughly the task is as follows. The user enters the value in the input, then the entered value will be converted to the svg path and sent to the backend. Entered values should be sensitive to font changes but this is at a later stage.

Input: Verb 
Ouput: https://jsfiddle.net/4uhwsjvk/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    state = {
    value: 'hi'
  };

  handleInputEvent = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('create svg from input value');
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputEvent} />
        <button>submit</button>
      </form>

      {this.state.value}
    </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1wda3bj7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in a browser, there is no way to access the glyph shapes of fonts or a string of text.

There are, however, third party Javascript libraries that will be useful to you.  For example opentype.js:

https://opentype.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

In your case, you want to map every letter to a pre-defined SVG, an example of a possible solution:

```
const SVG_LETTERS = {
  a: <svg .../>,
  A: <svg .../>
};

class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 'hi'
  };

  handleInputEvent = e => {...};

  handleSubmit = e => {...};

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        ...

        {[...value].map(char => SVG_LETTERS[char])}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

> Old Answer

You should treat a SVG as a `ReactElement`:

```
const CoolSVG = ({ pathString }) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="24"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    fill="none"
    stroke="currentColor"
    strokeWidth="2"
    strokeLinecap="round"
    strokeLinejoin="round"
    className="feather feather-github"
  >
    <path d={pathString} />
  </svg>
);

const CoolPath =
  'M9 19c-5 1.5-5-2.5-7-3m14 6v-3.87a3.37 3.37 0 0 0-.94-2.61c3.14-.35 6.44-1.54 6.44-7A5.44 5.44 0 0 0 20 4.77 5.07 5.07 0 0 0 19.91 1S18.73.65 16 2.48a13.38 13.38 0 0 0-7 0C6.27.65 5.09 1 5.09 1A5.07 5.07 0 0 0 5 4.77a5.44 5.44 0 0 0-1.5 3.78c0 5.42 3.3 6.61 6.44 7A3.37 3.37 0 0 0 9 18.13V22';

const DEFAULT_INITIAL = 'Copy the above path';

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(DEFAULT_INITIAL);
  const onChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Typography.Text code>{CoolPath}</Typography.Text>
      <br />
      <Input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <br />
      <CoolSVG pathString={value} />
    </FlexBox>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]

Comment: Nice kitty :) But its not the case. I want to 'generate' this CoolPath value. 'M9.. etc'. You entered svg path and kitty showed. I want to enter text and generete svg path from this text.

Comment: Edit your question and add an example of desired input and output

Comment: Also, “adding a path” is exatcly how it means

Comment: Another example. Imagine you typed Verb into input. The output should be like this https://jsfiddle.net/4uhwsjvk/ The path tag in svg element

Comment: So where is the problem, define a svg for each letter and send its id to backend, its too broad question by the way.

Comment: I cannot use <text> tag. I need path because svg has to be sensitive to font change.

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't think it's possible to render a single path from a value as you want.

Comment: Here is another example for @RobertLongson just different font and the same input https://jsfiddle.net/ho21bdxe/2/

Comment: DennisVash i think your solution wont help me create svg path. And this is what i rly need. Another examples are in comment above.

Comment: There are so many dependencies needed to be concerned to create such path depending on input, as I mentioned, you can pre-define the paths, either way, this question is too broad.